# I cannot join any chat room after my new account merged with the old one

Tags: bug, status-completed, reputation, chat, user-accounts

I have a new account that has been merged with the old one. My reputation is greater than 20. But the chat room still says I must have at least 20 reps to join a room. What is wrong?

Comment: Occasionally the system 'looses' your login. Have you tried logging out, restarting your browser and logging in again before trying to access chat?

Comment: @JosephWright: I will try now. It does not work. Still cannot join.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Should work now. The merge confused chat, I'm not yet sure why, but your chat account is now repaired.